# What are the common Quality Assurance jokes?

Tags: automated-testing

I have seen lots and lots of jokes of programming. But there are very few jokes about QA. I feel sorry for that. So it very much needed to make our our own kind of jokes repo. And as i have no reputation to make a tag, can any one please make a tag for it also.

Comment: The question solicits jokes, and this is not a joke site.

Comment: I know this is not a joke site @user246. Don't take it seriously. I just want to log all kind of jokes in a page so that we don't have to wander anywhere. It is kind of a thread that you will only update if you stumble upon any hilarious bug that make you laugh and share it with us. :)

Answer (score 3):

I would like to answer we are too serious for jokes but... 
http://extremesoftwaretesting.com/Humor/JokesSoftwareTesting.html

Comment: Don't we need humor!! Man i was thinking that we are funny people and we find bugs. Every bug is not so serious. Don't we even stumble upon bugs that causes to laugh. Can't we share these bugs??

Comment: Of course we need, don't take it seriously :D

Answer (score 1):

I am giving an answer first as i have stumbled upon in google.

[image: SQA Jokes for SQA engineers]